# Unable to view tooltip info on bootstrap table data cell hover

Tags: bootstrap-4

Made a responsive table using bootstrap version 4.1.3. in which each data cell
has a info icon linked with a tooltip, whose purpose is to show some info on its hover. 
But my problem if table has only one rows/tr then tooltip is not visible when hovered over icon whereas with muliple rows/tr it works just fine.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: hi Monika, please find the code,

Comment: unable to past my code snippet here

Comment: how to add code here